# How could a PySpark RDD linear list be converted to a DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I'd like to convert a linear list to a dataframe.
i.e. given the following list,

```
a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"]
```

Expected result is,

```
+--------------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+--------------------+
|  a1  |  a2  |  a3  |
|  b1  |  b2  |  b3  |
|  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |
+--------------------+
```

I tried the following but got an error.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"]

rdd = sc.parallelize(a)

schema = StructType([
     StructField("a", StringType(), True),
     StructField("b", StringType(), True),
     StructField("c", StringType(), True)
     ])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.show()
```

The last show() statement gets an error "Job aborted due to stage failure".
Please someone tell me the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to convert `a` to be in the form: `[('a1', 'a2', 'a3'), ('b1', 'b2', 'b3'), ('c1', 'c2', 'c3')]`

Comment: The list is given, therefore can’t re-write it. Looking for something similar to ‘reshape’ in NumPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559003/how-could-a-pyspark-rdd-linear-list-be-converted-to-a-dataframe#comment97864738_55559003), I presume that you start with the `rdd` and not the list.

I further assume that you are determining order based on the index of the `rdd`. If these assumptions are correct, you can use `zipWithIndex()` to add a row number to each record.

Then divide the row number by 3 (use integer division) to group every 3 consecutive records. Next use `groupByKey()` to aggregate the records with the same `key` into a tuple.

Finally, drop the key and call `toDF()`

```python
rdd.zipWithIndex()\
    .map(lambda row: (row[1]//3, row[0]))\
    .groupByKey()\
    .map(lambda row: tuple(row[1]))\
    .toDF(["a", "b", "c"])\
    .show()
#+---+---+---+
#|  a|  b|  c|
#+---+---+---+
#| a1| a2| a3|
#| c1| c2| c3|
#| b1| b2| b3|
#+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that should hopefully meet your criteria

```
# First get a 1 column DF
df = sql.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(a).map(lambda x: [x]), schema=['col'])
# split each value into a number and letter e.g. 'a1' --> ['a','1']) 
df = df.withColumn('letter', f.split('col', '').getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn('number', f.split('col', '').getItem(1))

# Now pivot to get what you want (dropping extraneous columns and ordering 
# to get exact output

output = (df.groupBy('letter')
          .pivot('number')
          .agg(f.first('col'))
          .select([f.col(column).alias('col%s'%(column)) for column in ['1','2','3']])
          .orderBy('col1')
          .drop('letter'))
```

Comment: I am fairly certain that `a1`, `a2`, ... etc were examples and not meant to be taken as literal values.

Comment: actually I think it's a bit ambiguous, I interpreted it is a sequence of 4 types (a, b and c) with only the top 3 examples of each shown (i.e. subset of a much larger list of a's, b's and c's with corresponding index numbers). However, it's not really for either of us to say which is correct.

Comment: Agreed it's ambiguous. I'm going by the comment that OP is looking for something similar to numpy's reshape.

Comment: Thank you ages29 and pault, and sorry for my ambiguity.
I confirmed that the solution by pault was what I expected. 
Thanks again!